# Use different values for Depth Test and Depth Write in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, particles, depth-buffer, alpha-blending

Is there a way to use something similar to PolygonOffset to make a depth test more permissive (move fragment depth towards eye) but still write the original depth value to the depth buffer? The only thing I can come up with is a tricky two pass solution using a stencil buffer, but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Context of my question: We have an entity with a particle based smoke plume that is often in front of a semi-transparent building. Do to some constraints with batching, the building gets drawn after the smoke plume. Originally the smoke plume particles were rendered with a depth test but no depth write. This caused the building to be drawn on top of the smoke.

Turning the depth write on for the smoke particles fixes the building, but now the smoke particles interfere with each other. Ideally, I'd like to find a way for them to stop interfering while still writing to the depth buffer.

Comment: Did you take a look at `glDepthFunc`? https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glDepthFunc.xml

Comment: If you "lie" with the depth testing, you'll eventually get some other undesirable artifact, where the smoke appears in front of something it should be behind. I think you should revisit how to draw the smoke last...

Answer (score 1):

I ***think*** you may be interested in [`glDepthRange (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDepthRange.xhtml). That affects the mapping from NDC [**-1.0**,**1.0**] to window-space Z (the depth buffer stores window-space Z) during the viewport transformation. Effectively the nearplane becomes `nearVal` and the farplane becomes `farVal`. You can fool with this to bias and/or rescale your assigned depth values, but GL clamps these values to [**0.0**,**1.0**].

Since all testing is done in window-space, you can simply modify the mapping between passes to make depth tests more *"permissive."* If you are clever, you can even reverse the mapping and the direction of the test to alter precision distribution.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I think this will still write the biased window-space Z value to the depth buffer, instead of the original value. This might be useful if I was drawing the smoke particles individually (I could call glDepthRange after each particle to sequentially push the near plane forward), but they're currently being rendered with one draw command.

Comment: @Shadow503 Ah, I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do originally. I thought you just wanted to draw the smoke ***always*** in front of the building, but with depth testing between particles. That could have been solved by dividing the scene into two discrete depth ranges. May I ask what hardware you are targeting? There is a GL4 era feature called conservative depth that will allow you to test using the original depth, but write a different one. I know that is the reverse of what you want, but I think you can tweak some things to make it useful.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for; I'll check it out!

Comment: I've been trying to use ARB_conservative_depth extension. I managed to get it running but I found that the early z test doesn't appear to be happening. Is it possible alpha blending is preventing early z from occurring?

Comment: Alpha blending will not prevent it from working, alpha testing on the other hand will. That is to say, if you use `discard` in your fragment shader. You may need to add `layout(early_fragment_tests) in;` to the beginning of your fragment shader to ***force*** this behavior. That said, if you are using alpha blending then you already have a pretty strict required draw order, I am not sure why you want to write to the depth buffer at all in this situation?

Comment: I think what I'm trying to do is impossible and I need to focus my efforts on fixing my alpha sorting issues instead. Reading the [OpenGL wiki page on Fragment Shaders](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Outputs), it seems that  violating the condition specified in the layout statement results in undefined behavior, so I'm limited to the <depth_greater> or <depth_any> conditions. When I tested it on my GTX 285, it would still reject fragments that should have passed if the depth test was done with the unmodified depth. This card also doesn't support ARB_SHADER_IMAGE_LOAD_STORE.